# 406 error of cpanel

Tags: cpanel, bugzilla

I have installed bugzilla on my cpanel. But while creating a new bug it display 406 error

> Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource /bugzilla/post_bug.cgi could not be found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please give me a solution to solve this issue. I googled a lot and found that it can be a server issue. But i dont know how to resolve this on server.

Comment: You have two error numbers, 406 in the title and 404 in the body.  You should consider updating the title to 404.

Answer (score 3):

Your are using mod_security?

Try see log file.

```
tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/modsec_audit.log
```

Comment: i have added the code. <IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule> in .htaccess file. but still my issue is not resolved.

Comment: mod_sexcurity.c it's for Old module. New Module don't work on htaccess
You must see log, and get ID Rule and put this rule on modsec2.whitelist.conf or modsec2.user.conf (Depend your config)